# Gaussian Process scikit-learn - Exception

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, gaussian, forecasting

I want to use Gaussian Processes to solve a regression task. My data is as follow : each X vector has a length of 37, and each Y vector has a length of 8.

I'm using the `sklearn`package in `Python` but trying to use gaussian processes leads to an `Exception`:

```
from sklearn import gaussian_process

print "x :", x__
print "y :", y__

gp = gaussian_process.GaussianProcess(theta0=1e-2, thetaL=1e-4, thetaU=1e-1)
gp.fit(x__, y__)
```

> x : [[  136.   137.   137.   132.   130.   130.   132.   133.   134.
>   135.
>       135.   134.   134.  1139.  1019.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
>         0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
>        70.    24.    55.     0.     9.     0.     0.]  [  136.   137.   137.   132.   130.   130.   132.   133.   134.   135.
>       135.   134.   134.  1139.  1019.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
>         0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
>        70.    24.    55.     0.     9.     0.     0.]  [   82.    76.    80.   103.   135.   155.   159.   156.   145.   138.
>       130.   122.   122.   689.   569.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
>         0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
>         0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]  [  156.   145.   138.   130.   122.   118.   113.   111.   105.   101.
>        98.    95.    95.   759.   639.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
>         0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
>         0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]  [  112.   111.   111.   114.   114.   113.   114.   114.   112.   111.
>       109.   109.   109.  1109.   989.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
>         0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
>         0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]  [  133.   130.   125.   124.   124.   123.   103.    87.    96.   121.
>       122.   123.   123.   399.   279.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
>         0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
>         0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]  [  104.   109.   111.   106.    91.    86.   117.   123.   123.   120.
>       121.   115.   115.   549.   429.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
>         0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
>         0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]  [  144.   138.   126.   122.   119.   118.   116.   114.   107.   105.
>       106.   119.   119.   479.   359.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
>         0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
>         0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.]]
>
> y : [[  7.           9.          13.          30.          34.          37.
>      36.          41.        ]  [  7.           9.          13.          30.          34.          37.
>      36.          41.        ]  [ -4.          -9.         -17.         -21.         -27.         -28.   -28.         -20.        ]  [ -1.          -1.          -4.          -5.          20.          28.
>      31.          23.        ]  [ -1.          -2.          -3.          -1.          -4.          -7.
>       8.          58.        ]  [ -1.          -2.         -14.33333333 -14.         -13.66666667 -32.   -26.66666667  -1.        ]  [  1.           3.33333333   0.          -0.66666667   3.           6.
>      22.          54.        ]  [ -2.          -8.         -11.         -17.         -17.         -16.   -16.         -23.        ]]
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        11 gp = gaussian_process.GaussianProcess(theta0=1e-2, thetaL=1e-4, thetaU=1e-1)
>        12 
>   ---> 13 gp.fit(x__, y__)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/gaussian_process/gaussian_process.pyc
>   in fit(self, X, y)
>       300         if (np.min(np.sum(D, axis=1)) == 0.
>       301                 and self.corr != correlation.pure_nugget):
>   --> 302             raise Exception("Multiple input features cannot have the same"
>       303                             " target value.")
>       304
>
> Exception: Multiple input features cannot have the same target value.

I've found [some topics related to a `scikit-learn` issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4916), but my version is up-to-date.

Comment: As per the suggestion in the issue, did you try to comment out `line 307` in `gaussian_process.py`?

Comment: Thanks @erip , it does solve -momentarily- the problem !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is known [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4916) and it still has not actually been resolved.

It is happens, because if you have same points , your matrix is not invertible(singular).(meaning you cannot calculate A^-1 - which is part of solution for GP).

In order to solve it, just add some small  gaussian noise to your examples or use other [GP](https://github.com/SheffieldML/GPy) library.

You can always try to implement it, it is actually not that hard. The most important thing in GP is your kernel function, for example gaussian kernel:

```
exponential_kernel = lambda x, y, params: params[0] * \
    np.exp( -0.5 * params[1] * np.sum((x - y)**2) )
```

Now, we need to build covariance matrix, like this:

```
covariance = lambda kernel, x, y, params: \
    np.array([[kernel(xi, yi, params) for xi in x] for yi in y])
```

So, when you want to predict new point `x` calculate its covariance:

```
sigma1 = covariance(exponential_kernel, x, x, theta)
```

and apply following:

```
def predict(x, data, kernel, params, sigma, t):
    k = [kernel(x, y, params) for y in data]
    Sinv = np.linalg.inv(sigma)
    y_pred = np.dot(k, Sinv).dot(t)
    sigma_new = kernel(x, x, params) - np.dot(k, Sinv).dot(k)
    return y_pred, sigma_new
```

This is very naive implementation and for data with high dimensions, runtime will be high. Hardest thing to calculate here is  `Sinv = np.linalg.inv(sigma)` which takes `O(N^3)`.

Comment: Thanks ! I've been trying to use GPy but I failed. With this trick it now works.

Comment: A side note - this seems like a good suggestion for resolving the issue in the library. I recommend suggesting this if it hasn't been done yet. +1 for the mathematical suggestion instead of the kludge I suggested. :)

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem, but I am not really sure how to use this very nice trick in my case. I have the following 3 lines: 

gp = GaussianProcess(theta0=0.3, nugget=2.4)
gp.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
y_pred, sigma = gp.predict(xtest, eval_MSE=True)

Then, who is who? How the "fit" is carried out using Farseer's suggestion? So I calculate the "exponential_kernel", the "covariance" and "sigma" and call predict, but how the fitting/training is done? Thanks

Comment: It's helpful to see you explaining the heavy run time part and giving its order.