# How to use input features with the same target value with Scikit Learn's Gaussian Processes

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, gaussian

I am new to Scikit Learn and am trying to learn how to use Gaussian process regression.

I am attempting to use a data-set that has repeated numbers, for example:

```
array(x,y) = [[10, 10, 20, 20, 15, 17], [30, 40, 50, 60, 50, 40]]
```

When following the documentation for Gaussian process regression with Scikit Learn, i'm encountering the following problem:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\gaussian_process\gaussian_process.pyc in fit(self, X, y)
    298         if (np.min(np.sum(D, axis=1)) == 0.
    299                 and self.corr != correlation.pure_nugget):
--> 300             raise Exception("Multiple input features cannot have the same"
    301                             " target value.")
    302     
Exception: Multiple input features cannot have the same target value.
```

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcess


#Import CSV file
dataset = np.loadtxt(open("data.csv","rb"),delimiter=",",skiprows=1)

#Separate CSV file columns into X,Y
X = np.atleast_2d(dataset[:,0]).T
y = dataset[:,1].ravel()

#set values for x-axis plot 
min = np.amin(dataset[:,0])
max = np.amax(dataset[:,0])

x = np.atleast_2d(np.linspace(min, max, 1000)).T

# Instanciate a Gaussian Process model
gp = GaussianProcess(corr='cubic', theta0=1e-2, thetaL=1e-4, thetaU=1e-1,
                     random_start=100)

# Fit to data using Maximum Likelihood Estimation of the parameters
gp.fit(X, y)
```

Is it possible to have repeated values in the input data-set? If so, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: Which version of scikit-learn are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gaussian Process scikit-learn - Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34723703/gaussian-process-scikit-learn-exception)

Comment: I'm using the most recent version. Can't seem to fix with above previous question

Comment: I've also tried adding noise to the input variable as well as increasing the nugget, both give the same response.